# How to name tag for raster package for R?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I need to create [raster](/questions/tagged/raster) tag for [raster package for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html). The problem is that the [raster](/questions/tagged/raster) already exists and means general array of pixels.

So how should I name the tag for the R package? These tags normaly use the name of the R package, but now it is not possible. I was considering [r-raster](/questions/tagged/r-raster), doesn't look good, but it's the best I have in mind.

Comment: Why not just [tag:raster-package] ?

Comment: Seems like that could have the same issue as well with some other rastering package, no?  Given `raster` has more than one (english) meaning here, tagging it specifically to `r` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Joe Good point, yes.

Comment: Aaah, @joran, nice to see you, as a [tag:r] guru! How did you find this question so fast? Do you have a stackexchange query for [tag:R] tag accross all sites? :-) Anyway: I think I like [tag:r-raster] more because it shows it belongs to R (there could be other frameworks using packages). Have you encountered a similar case during your [tag:r] career here?

Comment: @Tomas I simply spend too much time on Meta, that's all. And I was just brainstorming, but Joe's right, r-raster is better.

Comment: OK, thanks @joran! I will go for [tag:r-raster].

Comment: @joran, I see :) I sometimes find myself browsing on Meta too much too. I think it is not even healthy :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[r-raster](/questions/tagged/r-raster) seems like the best solution to me, assuming it's sufficiently used to justify a tag.  Similar to [sas-macro](/questions/tagged/sas-macro) etc.  Makes me wish SO had a sub-tag concept though (tags that aren't intended to be used in and of themselves, but ONLY as tags along with a language tag or other big-scope tag).

Comment: +1 for subtags.  I do think `r-raster` is the best choice (and that there should be some standard that all packages be listed this way), but subtags would mean a person starting to type "rast[...]" would have the right tag pop up easily (as long as they had added the `r` tag first, but that seems likely!)